# Does the Prose Edda have a Hungarian translation?

Tags: norse, prose-edda, translation

This question is [cross-posted at hu.wikipedia](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Tudakoz%C3%B3/Arch%C3%ADvum/2015-07-12#Pr.C3.B3zai_Edda_magyar_ford.C3.ADt.C3.A1sa) where it's also on-topic, because that site has some mythology enthusiasts.

**Does the Prose Edda have a translation to Hungarian?**  If it does, please give any details you know and availability of the volume it was published in.

I know that it has translations to at least English, French, German, Norwegian, and Finnish.

The Prose Edda is not the same as Poetic Edda, but a later work.  The Poetic Edda does have at least one Hungarian translation by Tandori Dezső, of which [the main text is available online at MEK](http://mek.oszk.hu/00300/00377/).  The online copy does not appear to contain the Prose Edda.  (Correct me if I'm wrong here.)  I shall still look at translations of the Poetic Edda (there's at least two different books, one containing this translation, and one containing an unknown translation), both for its own right and because maybe they do contain or refer me to a translation of the Prose Edda.

Comment: [Proza-Edda magyarul](https://sites.google.com/site/gestrgangleri/proza-edda---magyarul)

Comment: @Neeshka Interesting. Looks like a translation project someone started, gave up after one chapter, and put online.

Answer (score 2):

Towards an answer:

You might look [here](https://rootsofyggdrasil.wordpress.com/magyar-nyelvu-forrasok-forditasok/).  Beke's *Stories From the Edda* may (or may not!) be (all or part of) Snorra Edda.

Perhaps better, István Bernáth's *[Skandináv Mitológia](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8861889-skandin-v-mitol-gia)* appears to contain an Hungarian translation of Snorra Edda along with scholarly essays and other translations.